# Unable to use mouse and keyboard in Lightdm test mode

Tags: lightdm

I have a Debian Buster as a VirtualBox guest, and when I run

`/usr/bin/lightdm --test-mode --debug`

I am unable to use both mouse and keyboard. (Ctrl+Shift does not help)

it outputs:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /home/user/.cache/lightdm/log/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.26.0, UID=1000 PID=7884
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/xfce4/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Running in user mode
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.02s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.03s] WARNING: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Loading user config from /etc/lightdm/users.conf
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User user added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.03s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display
[+0.03s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Logging to /home/user/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1.log
[+0.03s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Writing X server authority to /home/user/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+0.04s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Launching X Server
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Launching process 7889: /usr/bin/Xephyr :1 -seat seat0 -auth /home/user/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1 -nolisten tcp
[+0.04s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting XDMCP server on UDP/IP port 177
[+0.04s] WARNING: Failed to create IPv4 XDMCP socket: Error binding to address: Permission denied
[+0.04s] WARNING: Failed to create IPv6 XDMCP socket: Error binding to address: Invalid argument
[+0.04s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested) 
/bin/rm: no se puede borrar '/var/lib/lightdm/data/lightdm': Permiso denegado
[+0.15s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 7889
[+0.15s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Got signal from X server :1
[+0.15s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Connecting to XServer :1
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'user'

** (process:7894): WARNING **: 10:40:04.829: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data/user
[+0.19s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Logging to /home/user/.cache/lightdm/log/seat0-greeter.log
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Session pid=7909: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+0.52s] DEBUG: Session pid=7909: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+0.52s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
^C[+9.62s] DEBUG: Got signal 2 from process 0
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Caught Interrupt signal, shutting down
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 7889
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Sending SIGTERM
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+9.62s] DEBUG: Session pid=7909: Sending SIGTERM
[+9.63s] DEBUG: Session pid=7909: Terminated with signal 2
[+9.63s] DEBUG: Session: Failed during authentication
[+9.63s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+9.63s] DEBUG: Session pid=7894: Terminated with signal 2
[+9.63s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Process 7889 exited with return value 0
[+9.64s] DEBUG: XServer 1: X server stopped
[+9.64s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Removing X server authority /home/user/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+9.64s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 0
```

Any ideas?